My laptop HP Pavilion gets hot and battery drains on suspend mode using Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
I’m using Ubuntu 24.04 on my HP Pavilion Laptop 15 equipped with an 11th Gen Intel® Core™ i5-1155G7 processor (8 cores) and the Linux 6.8.0-35-generic kernel.
When I close the lid or when my laptop enters suspend mode after a period of inactivity, it becomes excessively hot and occasionally powers off. Additionally, if the laptop is not connected to a power source, the battery drains completely.
Is there something I can do ?

It gets hot most likely because the fans do not run. It shuts down as it reaches a thermal cut off temp, a safety feature. Until a fix is found I suggest you not use suspend. Having thermal cut off over and over can damaged the hardware.

I am having this (or a similar) issue with an Asus Vivobook (i7 processor). Apparently, the suspend command only switches off the screen, everything else seems to keep running and draining the battery. All the while the sleep state is set to deep. Please post if you find a solution.

Since i switched to ubuntu 24.10, the problem's gone. I guess the issue had something to do with the linux kernel. I also noticed that the configuration for the suspend mode has changed in this new Ubuntu version and might have something to do with the fix of this issue.

I come back with more feedback after a few days... I no longer have issues with either the fan or the battery, so it’s safe to say that since I upgraded to Ubuntu 24.10 with the new version of the kernel, everything is fixed.
